# Can you bind a reference to an uninitialized member?

Tags: c++, reference

Short question, is the following ok:

```
struct X
{
    A& x;
    A  y;
    X() : x(y) {}
};
```

Reversing the order of the two members in the struct is definitely ok, since it guarantees `y` is initialized first, but does this work or invoke UB?

Moreso, would the following be ok:

```
struct X
{
   X& x;
   X() : x(*this) {}
};
```

?

Comment: Q: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @paulsm4: Why does that matter? He asked if it was undefined behavior. The effect could still "work" on a particular compiler even if it is undefined.

Comment: *Reversing the order of the two members in the struct is definitely ok, since it guarantees y is initialized first* ... that is true only if `A` is non POD class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that would invoke undefined behavior.

I don't see that case is any different from this:

```
 int *p = new int;
```

The expression `new int` is a pointer to an *uninitialized* int. Here we are initializing the *pointer* `p` with `new int`. The *content* is not read.

Similarly,

```
 int & r = *p; //or *new int
```

Here we are initializing the *reference* `r` with `*p`. The *content* is not read

In both cases, the *content* is not read. **Reading an uninitialized variable invokes undefined behavior**. In both cases, it is the *content* which is uninitialized, not the *address*, and we are not *reading* the content.

Comment: For those who want the keywords: dereferencing results in an lvalue. The UB from uninitialized variables comes from the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which the technical part of 'reading the variable'. Because we're only getting an lvalue reference to an uninitialized object, it's okay. Once something causes that conversion to an rvalue, the requirement that the something be initialized kicks in.

Comment: @GManNickG: Thanks for the vocabulary and the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The reference and the variable are distinct things each has its own "initialization".

The purpose of a reference is to *refer to `something`*. The only prerequisite is that `something` physically exist. Whatever its state is well defined or not is all another story.

The initialization of the reference is not UB. It can be UB its use, before what it refer had been given a value, but this is no more no less what you get when using an initialized variable.

Different thing is `X() :x(*this) {}`

Here you are giving to a function (the x constructor) a pointer to something that is not yet been fully constructed. This is "dangerous" since -in general- you don't know what that function will do with that pointer and if it expects or not it to be somehow "flawled". May be it just "store it for later use" (hence no problem) may be it deference it to access ... unreconstructed members!
It is something a compiler should at least warn about.

Of course, in this particular case (you are just initializing a reference) it will not be a problem since a "reference contructor" don't access the referred object. But in general is not a good idea.

Comment: The two are similar, even if talking about `y` or `*this` - they are both not fully constructed. Actually, what do you mean by constructed? Initialized?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: In this particular case the two things coincide. But in general they don't.

Imagine a struct with many members. When the ctor or -let's say- the third one is called, the fourth is not contructed. By passing *this to the third you may have the ctor of the third using *this to access the fouth memebr. This can be UB since may be it don't expect it to be uninitialized. Or it can assign some values in the 4th memebr's members... that will be wiped out by the 4th ctor soon later.

Comment: This is something in your case is granted to never happen (contructing a reference doesn't "use" the referred), but *this, before the `{` has to be considered still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would make sense to split this issue into several other points:

1. Is this syntactically correct and does this allow only one implementation?
2. Can this code lead to crashes and high level issues?
3. Should the compiler take care of the second?

I would answer: Y, Y, Y/N.

I do not see ambiguity in the samples of the code above. There are millions of ways how syntactically correct code would corrupt memory, crash, etc. This is yet another example.

Compiler may issue a warning, because the examples above are obvious. In a real scenario with a lot of indirections, redefinitions, etc, compiler may get confused. I would not blame it too hard. Algorithmic analysis is a job of another tool, not the compiler.

For example the code below is perfectly fine:

```
int *p = NULL;
int &r = *p;
```

This is NULL reference. Nothing special.

These are my 2 cents.